# Redirect if field from mysql is completed

Tags: php, mysql

I want to redirect a user to error.html if a user tries to login but has already logged in and selected their preference before.

I have added `if ( $rows['attendance'] == "yes" ) || ( $rows['attendance'] == "no" ); {
    header('location: error.html');`

the attendance field in mysql has either yes or no if they have logged in and selected their preference before. but the code above is not working for me

```
// Check username and password match
    if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
            // Set username session variable
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            // Jump to secured page
               $row = mysql_fetch_array($login);

    switch ($row['attendance']):
        case 1:
            header('Location: page1.php');
            exit;
        case 2:
            header('Location: page2.php');
            exit;
         case 3:
            header('Location: page3.php');
            exit;
         case 4:
            header('Location: page4.html');
            exit;
         case 5:
            header('Location: page5.html');
            exit;
            endswitch;

     if ( $rows['attendance'] == "yes" ) || ( $rows['attendance'] == "no" ); {
    header('location: error.html');
    }
    }
    else {
            // Jump to login page
            header('Location: login.php');
    }

    ?>

        enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon after the `if` statement but before its body.

Remove the semicolon which follows the close-parentheses of the `if`. Your code as it is written says "if [condition], do nothing. Then redirect."

General advice side note: "is not working" is not a helpful problem description. Always describe what the code does, and how this differs from what you expect.

Comment: it is still not working.
the broswer page shows the location of page that the script above is on. So it runs through the code but does not actually do anything

Comment: @user1191294 The header should be capital-'L' `Location`.

Comment: are the {} in the correct position and am i using correct if else statements where they should be

Comment: @user1191294 The braces are in the right spot.

Comment: if i take out [PHP] if ( $row['attendance'] == "Yes" ) || ( $row['attendance'] == "No" ) { header('Location: error.html'); } [/PHP]it works as it should be i need that statement to work. if that row in mysql is Yes or No redirect to error.html